# Created an ISO from a DVD, but now the ISO is too large to go back onto DVD?

Tags: iso, dvd

I've been copying VHS home movies onto writable DVDs, then ripping the DVDs to ISOs on Ubuntu 1604.  Some of the ISOs appear to be too large to rewrite onto DVDs (e.g. 4,700,372,922 bytes == too large, whereas 4,677,468,160 bytes == fits).  I don't understand how the too-large ISO could have fit on the writable DVD in the first place.  Is this just some odd artifact of the ext filesystem?  I need to know if it's possible to get that too-large ISO back onto a DVD.

Comment: Check the capacity of the dvd, and remember some space on it is used for formatting too. You added `22904762` to the original size, check the size used for formatting. `usable capacity = dvd capacity - formatting space size`. if `usable capacity` is less than the new size, then it won't fit.

Comment: But the ISO was created *from* a 4.7G DVD+R, so I don't understand how it could be larger than the 4.7G DVD+R that I want to write it back onto.  It would be different if I created the ISO from a file roller process, as its size would be my fault for how much I crammed into it.  But how does the content of one 4.7G DVD+R become an ISO that's larger than its source disk?

Comment: Formatting changes a lot of things and especially file size.